# What's the explanation of this Logical OR (II) JavaScript expression?

Tags: javascript

I'm going through a **W3 schools** [tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/graphics/game_controllers.asp) on game controllers and there is an expression `myGameArea.keys = (myGameArea.keys || [])` which I'm having trouble understanding and it would be great if someone could explain in detail what's the logic behind.

### Tutorial explanation

What if more than one key is pressed at the same time?

In the example above, the component can only move horizontally or vertically. Now we want the component to also move diagonally.

Create a keys array for the myGameArea object, and insert one element for each key that is pressed, and give it the value true , the value remains true untill the key is no longer pressed, the value becomes false in the keyup event listener function:

### Context of the expression

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
      myGameArea.keys = (myGameArea.keys || []);
      myGameArea.keys[e.keyCode] = true;
})
window.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
      myGameArea.keys[e.keyCode] = false;
})
```

### Full JavaScript code

```
var myGameArea = {
  canvas : document.createElement("canvas"),
  start : function() {
    this.canvas.width = 480;
    this.canvas.height = 270;
    this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
    document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas, document.body.childNodes[0]);
    this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 20);
    window.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
      myGameArea.keys = (myGameArea.keys || []);
      myGameArea.keys[e.keyCode] = true;
    })
    window.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
      myGameArea.keys[e.keyCode] = false;
    })
  },
  clear : function(){
    this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
  }
}

 function updateGameArea() {
  myGameArea.clear();
  myGamePiece.speedX = 0;
  myGamePiece.speedY = 0;
  if (myGameArea.keys && myGameArea.keys[37]) {myGamePiece.speedX = -1; }
  if (myGameArea.keys && myGameArea.keys[39]) {myGamePiece.speedX = 1; }
  if (myGameArea.keys && myGameArea.keys[38]) {myGamePiece.speedY = -1; }
  if (myGameArea.keys && myGameArea.keys[40]) {myGamePiece.speedY = 1; }
  myGamePiece.newPos();
  myGamePiece.update();
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR

Comment: If we do not already have a  `myGameArea.keys`  create it and initialise it to `[]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In most programming languages, `||` is an operator that takes two boolean values and performs a logical OR on them. (`true || false` is `true`, etc.)

Some languages, primarily dynamically typed ones in my experience, *generalize* the notion of `||` to work with other datatypes as well.

In JavaScript, `||` means the following:

- If the first value is falsy (`0`, `false`, `""`, `null`, `undefined`, `NaN`), return the second value.
- Otherwise, return the first value.

If you plug in some boolean values, you can see that this behavior mimmicks how `||` work in other languages.

Because of this behavior, `||` gains a secondary use as a "default value" operator, i.e. "use this value unless it's falsy, in which case use this other value instead".

For instance:

```js
let greeting = x || "Hello";
```

In the above code, `greeting` will be set to `x` unless `x` is falsy, in which case it'll instead be set to `"Hello"`.

Likewise,

```js
this.foo = this.foo || "Yo!";
```

The above code will initialize `this.foo` to `"Yo!"` if it doesn't already exist (or exists but has a falsy value).

Edit:

Looking at this specific example in OP's post:

```js
    window.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
      myGameArea.keys = (myGameArea.keys || []);
      myGameArea.keys[e.keyCode] = true;
    })
```

The line `myGameArea.keys = (myGameArea.keys || []);` ensures that the `myGameArea.keys` array exists, since it's never created before the event listener is registered and potentially invoked. You could explicitly add a `keys: []` to the `myGameArea` object to remove the need for this line altogether.

Additionally, the code also contains similar uses of the `&&` operator. As with `||`, it too has been generalized in JavaScript. It works like this:

- If the first value is falsy, return the first value.
- Otherwise, return the second value.

Looking at its use in the if statement:

```js
if (myGameArea.keys && myGameArea.keys[37]) { /*...*/ }
```

The `myGameArea.keys &&` is a way to short-circuit the second half of the condition. If `myGameArea.keys` was never created (for instance, because no button was ever pressed), we skip the rest of the condition which would otherwise have crashed since `myGameArea.keys` would be `undefined` and you cannot index (`[37]`) into the `undefined` value.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Could you please explain why they would use this Logical OR operator in that context? I'm having trouble understanding.

Comment: Super easy, to override a non given parameter in a function, if a parameter is not given you could assign a default. ex   myFunction(param){ param = param || "someDefault";   }

Comment: @Gass: I've expanded my answer to explain two specific pieces of the code.

Comment: @BambooleanLogic thanks a lot. What do you mean by this: If the first value is falsy, return the first value? ... I'm a little bit confused, should it be: if the first value is not falsy then return the first value?

Comment: @Gass No, what I wrote is correct. Again, let's compare to booleans: `false && true` is `false`. It doesn't matter what the second value is; the result is going to be `false` anyway. This is equivalent to saying "if the first value is false, return the first value". In JS, this is generalized to the almost identical "if the first value is _falsy_, return the first value".

Comment: To oversimplify the line of code a bit (meaning this description is what's _meant_, but not _strictly speaking_ exactly correct), `if (myGameArea.keys && myGameArea.keys[37])` essentially means is "if `myGameArea.keys` exists and its value for key `37` is `true`, then do something"

Comment: Ow sorry, I misunderstood, I thought you where referencing the OR operator above.